# use subdomain as username in meteor js

Tags: meteor, nginx, subdomain, kadira

**Problem**

On account creation I want the users to access their profile as username.domain-name.com

I also have website features as :

```
username.domain-name.com/feature1
username.domain-name.com/feature2
username.domain-name.com/feature3
```

Above links might have content which can be accessed by other users if above user has allowed him access.

Example:
`user1.domain-name.com/feature1`, here user1 has given access to user2 
Hence, user2 has logged in and on visiting `user1.domain-name.com/feature1` he should be able to see the content.

**My research so far:**

I tried following links:

`https://kadira.io/blog/meteor/sharing-meteor-login-state-between-sub-domains`
`https://github.com/jfrolich/meteor-subdomain-persistent-login`

After reading a lot, I found that meteor has localStorage as the way to store user login details. So, I have to somehow manage to pass the details to sub-domains. I also tried using proxy_pass in nginx config to do the following:
Request:
`username.domain-name.com/feature1` should be proxied to ( not re-direct URL would be same) `domain-name.com/username/feature1`

If someone would put some light here on the approach I should use would really help me.

I know this design might not be good for search engines.

**Update**

I am now successfully using following design:
if user1 is logged-in at domain-name.com and wants to visit his own profile page like user1.domain-name.com/profile.

Step1: user1 visits user1.domain-name.com/profile it redirects to domain-name.com where user1 had session in localstorage then reading HTTP header referrer I get user1.domain-name.com/profile and prepare new url:
user1.domain-name.com/profile?token=userToken (I might create another temp token in db with one click exp.)

Step2: redirect to new url user1.domain-name.com/profile?token=userToken, using get parameter i create new session in localstorage and redirect user1 back to user1.domain-name.com/profile.

This is very unconventional solution, I am still re-searching.

Comment: I don't see why this needs to be a different meteor site.  Why can't all of these domains point to the same application?

Comment: They all are pointing to same meteor application, I just have to find a working way of sharing login sessions among domain and all sub-domains